# Accessing Virtual Machine using Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a requirement of restarting my Compute Machine which is running on Google Cloud Platform using Cloud Functions.

Is there any way to do it using Cloud Function though compute have rest api's to access it but I am not so sure about it whether it will work on Cloud functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can reset a Google Cloud Compute instance using a Cloud Function.

You can follow the steps provided in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console#create_a_function) to create your Cloud Function and the index.js and package.json should be the following:

index.js

```
exports.resetting = function resetting() {
        var google = require('googleapis');
        var compute = google.compute('beta');

    authorize(function(authClient) {
      var request = {
        // Project ID for this request.
        project: 'YOUR-PROJECT-ID',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // The name of the zone for this request.
        zone: 'YOUR-INSTANCE-ZONE',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // Name of the instance scoping this request.
        instance: 'YOUR-INSTANCE-NAME',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        auth: authClient,
      };

      compute.instances.reset(request, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }

        // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
      });
    });
    function authorize(callback) {
      google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function(err, authClient) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('authentication failed: ', err);
          return;
        }
        if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
          var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];
          authClient = authClient.createScoped(scopes);
        }
        callback(authClient);
      });
    };
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "googleapis",
  "version": "24.0.0",
  "dependencies": {"googleapis":"^24.0.0"}
}
```

In the "function to execute" field that you will find when creating the Cloud Function you will need to enter the name of the function you are using, in this case "resetting"

Realize that you need to change the values for your project, zone, and instance in the index.js code that I provided.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console